# What rule arranges the selection grid for multiple windows of the same program?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gui

When I have multiple windows of the same program running (e.g. multiple documents in the same editor, or multiple terminal windows), and I click on the program's sidebar icon, and it shows a grid of reduced windows to pick which one I want to bring to the foreground, how is the arrangement of those windows determined? It seems that each time I select a window, if I click the program icon to see the selection again, the windows are in a different arrangement, but I haven't been able to figure out what rule is used to arrange the windows, so it has been a bit disorienting. If I knew how it arranged them, it might help.

Also, is there a way to affect the rule, and get it to not change the arrangement when a window is chosen? (That would help me when switching back and forth between a few files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not very comlpicated, but can indeed give an "at random" impression.

#### How it works

If we have four application windows:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

and we pick number `[2]`, it is moved to the end:

```
1, [2], 3, 4 ---> 1, 3, 4, 2
```

on the next time, we pick number 1:

```
[1], 3, 4, 2 ---> 3, 4, 2, 1
```

so in the end, things are pretty mixed up.

#### Can we work with fixed positions?

To me it seems unlikely this behaviour can be changed simply.

There is however an alternative: The Unity launcher in 14.04 shows the currently opened windows of an application, in a fixed order.

[image]